# BrowserSync client is crashing for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I have a webapp which is being built so it has several errors. However there are two errors which I didn't expect and they are avoiding the auto-refresh from BrowserSync.

This is my gulpfile.js where I have BrowserSync configured:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var estream = require('event-stream');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task("default", function () {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '.'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./app/assets/scss/*.scss', ['watch-sass']);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function () {
    console.log("Building...");
    runSequence(['compile-sass']);
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/scss/compiled', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('compile-sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/scss/compiled'));
});
gulp.task('watch-sass', ['compile-sass'], browserSync.reload);
```

and this is the error that shows up when the page loads the first time:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!